# With Rails 4.2, how to load JavaScript specific to one ControllerMethod Articles#New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, turbolinks

Currently, my application.js file includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is ckeditor is being loaded on every page when I only need it on one admin like view Articles#New.

What is the correct way in Rails 4.2, to make ckeditor's JS only load on the Articles#New view?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow some steps

1. Remove from application.js //= require ckeditor/init
2. at page `articles/new.html.erb` add following line

> javascript_include_tag "ckeditor/init"

3. in config/initializers/assets.rb add following lines

> ```
>   Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
> ```

Comment: Thanks but that is causing a JS error as `assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` is still being loaded by application.js

Comment: That worked locally but not in production. In prod, the site is trying to load `xxx.com/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=GB8C Failed` and the server is returning a 404

Answer (score 0):

I think @Vijay's answer is exactly the right one.
The config.js not found problem is another problem. The url is probably hard coded in the init.js, because "ckeditor/config.js" seems not like normal precompiled filename which usually looks like config-7efjsdhfduey44xxxxxx.js.

The assets/ dir only has precompiled files in production so the config.js is not found.

You can:

1. change `init.js` to `init.js.erb`
2. change every path it uses in the file to "asset_path", ex: 
   `'config.js` to `<%= asset_path 'ckeditor/config.js' %>`
3. do 1,2 for every file under ckeditor/

When using Sprocket in production, the right filename is important.
or you can just include the ckeditor from CDN and forget all about this j/k